# Why does my java code never end when i run it?

Tags: java, string, while-loop

I am writing a program that has 4 usernames and 4 passwords. If the user enters the right name with the right password, it then outputs "Welcome!". It only gives 2 tries. This is what I wrote, but when I run this code it doesn't end. It keeps asking for username non-stop. Can someone help me, guide on what I'm doing wrong, or what I am missing? Thanks.

```
public class password

{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int limit = 2;

        int count = 0;

        String[] user = {"Diana","Jasmin","Jimmy","Ross"};

        String[] passwords = {"Flower01","Cheer02","Reading03","Math04"};

        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter Username: ");
            String [] name = input.nextLine();

            if(user.equals(name))
            {
                while (count < user.length)
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter password: ");
                    String [] word = input.nextLine();

                    if (word.equals(passwords))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Welcome!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print("Sorry can not be found");
                       count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (true)`!! The bigger question is why would you expect it to ever end? The while loop will only end when the condition it's testing (here you're hard-coding `true`) is false, so this loop will never end since the condition never becomes false. Read up on while loops to understand the gory details. [While-loop tutorial link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: You ask us why it doesn't end. We ask you why you think it **should** end.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels He did say its his first Java class, he probably didnt see it. Simple mistake.

Comment: @jt15 did you mean to put something to be evaluated into the `while` condition and forget to do so? Because as others have said, that is the reason your code does not end.

Comment: @JohnnyCoder: I agree, which is why I didn't down-vote him and directed him to the tutorial. The question translated really is, "I don't understand how while loops work yet", and the correct answer for this type of question is: "study the tutorials; here's a link".

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I feel that's a bit of a problem with SO. Some people are really quick to downvote a question with a simple mistake, espicially for people who are new to programming. But that's a topic for meta I guess

Comment: @JohnnyCoder: the site's a bit hard on newbies, but it's not really meant to be a tutorial for the most basic aspects of the language. The original poster needs to read his text and his lesson notes, pure and simple. But a strong case can be made for deleting this question since it's unlikely to help folks in the future. Someone in a similar predicament who doesn't know how to do this, or how to look this up, likely won't know how to search this site for a similar question.

Comment: `String [] name = input.nextLine();` This shouldn't compile. I'm just confused now. Are you running code which didn't compile? Or is it different?

Comment: @Radiodef good spot. and I dont see a local or class variable that he simply forgot to put in there. Good question

Answer (score 2):

```
while(true) {...}
```

is a loop that never ends, you should put you condition at the place of the true.
You can for example add a second count for the first loop (here you want 4 I suppose).

```
String [] name = input.nextLine();
```

This line should not compile because you are assigning a string to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple cut of your code that works. Couple of things

1. Start Class name in capital.
2. You were reading input as `Array`which should really fail at compile time really.
3. You were not updating the count or displaying any thing if username is wrong.
4. Use `Println`to get new line after print.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password

{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int limit = 2;

        int count = 0;

        String[] user = {"Diana","Jasmin","Jimmy","Ross"};

        String[] passwords = {"Flower01","Cheer02","Reading03","Math04"};

        while (count <4)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter Username: ");
            String name = input.nextLine();

            if(user.equals(name))
            {
                while (count < user.length)
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter password: ");
                    String word = input.nextLine();

                    if (word.equals(passwords))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Welcome!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Sorry can not be found");
                       count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry can not be found");
               count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `while true` in your code. What you probably want to do, is to replace the `while true` with count and limit condition. Most of your code is already in place, you'll only need to replace the while true.

I'm also not sure why you have the second loop, which iterates over the users, sort of. I think what you can better do is replace the 2 arrays with a simple HashMap, something like this:

```
Map users = new HashMap();
users.put("name1", "password1");
users.put("name2", "password2");
users.put("name3", "password3");
users.put("name4", "password4");
```

And then, based on the username, you do a `users.get(username)` to get the password. Then, compare the password with the password the user typed. If it's correct, say welcome, if it's not correct, say error, and increment the counter. Then, if the counter is bigger than the max, stop the program. Hope that helps!